# PHP replace special characters from a string

Tags: php

I have **clean** function for remove special caracter from string but that function also removing Turkish caracter *(ı,ğ,ş,ç,ö)* from string

```
function clean($string) {
   $string = str_replace(' ', ' ', $string); 
   $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', ' ', $string); 

   return preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $string); 
}
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: It's doing exactly what you told it to - removing any characters that aren't A-Z, a-z, 0-9 or `-`. Try telling it not to remove letters, eg. `\p{L}`

Comment: For example : 
INPUT TEXT : Lisede sınıf ar'kad'aşım
OUTPUT : Lisede s n f arkada  m

I need : Lisede sınıf arkadaşım

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add those characters you want to keep to preg, also add Upper cases if neededç I edited your code:

```
function clean($string) {
    $string = str_replace(' ', ' ', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-ığşçöüÖÇŞİıĞ]/', ' ', $string);

    return preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $string);
}
```

Test:

```
$str='Merhaba=Türkiye 12345 çok çalış another one ! *, !@_';
var_dump(clean($str));
//Output: string(57) "Merhaba Türkiye 12345 çok çalış another one   "
```

Comment: Thank you my friend you save me from big troble

Answer (score 2):

You can use `iconv` to replacing special characters like à->a, è->e

```php
<?php
    $string = "ʿABBĀSĀBĀD";
    echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', $string);
    // output: [nothing, and you get a notice]
    echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//IGNORE', $string);
    // output: ABBSBD
    echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string);
    // output: ABBASABAD
    // Yay! That's what I wanted!
    ?>
```

Credits:

https://gist.github.com/swas/10643194

[@dmp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206861/dmp) y
[@Nisse Engström](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3478852/nisse-engstr%c3%b6m)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try:

```
function clean($string) {
   $string = str_replace(' ', ' ', $string); 
   $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9ĞİŞığşçö\-]/', ' ', $string); 

   return preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $string); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Which special characters you want to replace?
Maybe be it'll be easier to change a paradigm of cleaning from everything except ... to something concrete.

```
<?php

function garbagereplace($string) {

$garbagearray = array('@','#','$','%','^','&','*');
$garbagecount = count($garbagearray);
for ($i=0; $i<$garbagecount; $i++) {
$string = str_replace($garbagearray[$i], '-', $string);
}

return $string;
}

echo garbagereplace('text@#$text%^&*text');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following to remove accents from accented characters.

```
function removeAccents($subject){
  //Note:  This is not a complete list of accented characters
  $accented = array('ü','Ü','ú','È','É','Ê','Ë','é','ê','ë','è','£','Ğ','İ','Ş','ı','ğ','ş','ç','ö','Ÿ','ÿ','á','ñ','Ñ','À','Á','Â','Ã','Ä','Å');
  $clean = array('u','U','u','E','E','E','E','e','e','e','e','f','G','I','S','l','g','s','c','o','Y','y','a','n','N','A','A','A','A','A','A');

  $accentcount = count($accented);
  for ($i=0;$i<$accentcount;$i++){
    $subject = str_replace($accented[$i], $clean[$i], $subject);
  }
  return $subject;
}
```

For example:

```
removeAccents("el niño");
```

Returns "el nino"